# p for interaction in cohort study

Tags: p-value, interaction, cox-model, hazard

I have data from a cohort of 10,000 people who were followed for ten years to analyze the relationship between stress and the risk of dementia. The stress levels were independent variables, and the dementia incidence was response variable. I used the cox model to calculate the hazard ratios for dementia incidence according to stress levels.

Empirically, there may be different associations between men and women. Therefore, my intention is to analyze the data separately for each sex after conducting the overall analysis. However, if the interaction between sex and stress is greater than 0.10, does that imply that grouping by sex is unnecessary? In the analysis conducted separately for men and women, the hazard ratios between stress and dementia is 1.5 (1.1-1.9) for men and 0.9 (0.6-1.3) for women (Note that these were example values not the real values). Can it be concluded that there is a difference between men and women, even though the interaction between sex and stress is greater than 0.10?

If the p-value for the interaction is greater than 0.10, but there is a discernible difference in the results between men and women after stratification, should the stratified results for each sex still be reported?

Comment: Please provide more info. What is the response variable? And which model are you fitting? I assume that the numbers you provided are parameter estimates, but they are meaningless unless you tell us which model you used.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear description.  I have added them.

Comment: Are you sure you need the full generality of the Cox model? A fully parametric approach (e.g., a Weibull model with an interaction effect and possibly different shape parameters for men and women) would be much simpler.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind comments. I am not a professional statistician. Usually, we employ the Cox model to assess the association between risk factors, such as smoking or drinking, and the risk of diseases like cardiovascular disease or dementia. Then, I typically perform group analysis based on gender. However, someone recently informed me that I should not conduct gender or any other group analysis when the p-value for interaction is greater than 0.05. This has left me feeling confused, so I asked this question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Weibull model, but I'll look it up and make an effort to understand its methods. Nevertheless, the Cox model remains the mainstream approach for cohort study. If you could provide me with some suggestions related to Cox analysis, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a sample study for the cohort study I discussed.https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamainternalmedicine/fullarticle/1106008

Comment: Maybe this paper will help. It allows a different baseline hazard function for men and women AND different effects of stress for men and women.  https://med.stanford.edu/content/dam/sm/dbds/documents/biostats-workshop/Stratified-Cox-model-SIM-2012-.pdf

Comment: If the interaction isn't significant (which is what i think you mean by the interaction being greater that 0.1) then the sexes don't differ. You could still analyze them separately if you want, if say it's convention in your field to do so, but you shouldn't be drawing any conclusions about them being different.